# Are there different ways to store attribute table data?

Tags: arcmap, attribute-table, fields-attributes

I work in ArcMap 10.8.1. When a collegue of mine worked on a task of editing attribute tables of feature classes in a GDB (adding/deleting fields), he reported an error to me. It seems no changes were made to the attribute table outside of the .mxd file he worked in. The fields he edited stayed displayed in the attribute table when viewed inside .mxd but when opened separately in ArcCatalog, the fields were not changed.

How is it possible?

I think some time ago I read something about different ways of storing attribute data...

How come it is visible inside the .mxd in ArcMap but when I checked the feature class in gdb myself, no changes were seen?

[image]

Comment: Did you close all ArcMap instance connected to this specific .gdb ? did you try to compact the database ?

Comment: There are several different flavors of geodatabase, including file geodatabase and Enterprise geodatabase.  EGDBs can implement versioning, so that edits are not available in DEFAULT until posted.

Comment: Try making sure all edits were actually saved. Also definitely make sure all versions are reconciled and posted.

Comment: It is a file gdb. No versioning. All instances were closed.
at J.R Why compact the database?
@Stella how to make sure edits were saved? it's not an editing session, there is no save button when adding fields

Comment: In the original post I added a picture of attr in ArcMap and simultaneously in ArcCatalog. Fields in ArcCatalog are the original ones received from the data provider organization. Fields in ArcMap att table are the ones my collegue edited (added new fields, copied records, deleted original fields). How come I can see the edited fields in .mxd but not in ArcCatalog in the feature class file?

Comment: Have your investigated the Fields section of the properties for this particular layer?